# Find $\det(\mathrm{I} - 2\mathrm{P})$ where $\mathrm{P}\mathrm{P} = \mathrm{P}$ is a projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, determinant, projection, reflection

Let $\mathrm{P}$ be a well-defined $n\times n$ **projection matrix** and $\mathrm{I}$ be the identity matrix. What is the determinant of the following reflection matrix?
$$
\mathrm{R} = \mathrm{I} - 2\mathrm{P}
$$

> **Important**: The projection matrix in my case is always defined as $\mathrm{P} = \mathrm{A}^\top(\mathrm{A}\mathrm{A}^\top)^{-1}\mathrm{A}$ where $\mathrm{A}$ is a full row-rank $m\times n$ matrix with $n > m$.

#### Attempt following comments

The determinant of $\mathrm{R}$ is the product of its eigenvalues
$$
\det(\mathrm{R}) = \prod_{i=1}^n \lambda_i.
$$
Any non-zero vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$$
\mathrm{R}v = \lambda v
$$
is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$. This can be written
$$
(\mathrm{R} - \lambda \mathrm{I}) v = 0
$$
which has a non-zero solution only if $\det((1-\lambda)\mathrm{I} - 2\mathrm{P}) = 0$. However I am not sure how to show this.

Comment: I think you mean $P^2=P$. Also I think the determinant ought to be $(-1)^d$ where $d$ is the rank of $P$

Comment: @Math_Images_Only yes, I meant $P^2=P$ my bad

Comment: @Math_Images_Only How did you find $(-1)^{\text{rank}(P)}$?

Comment: Hint: the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues, and $P$ has very special eigenvalues..

Comment: It might also be instructive to think about what $R = I - 2 P$ does geometrically (if, say, $P$ is the projection onto a line through the origin).

Comment: This is false. Consider e.g. $P=0$ or $P=\operatorname{diag}(1,1,0,0,\ldots,0)$. If you mean that $P$ is a **rank-one** projection matrix, please specify so.

Comment: A few things that may help is that if $P$ is a projection to the subspace $W$ then $I-P$ is the projection on the orthogonal space $W^\bot$ meaning their images are orthogonal to each other. You also may see that $R=(I-P)-P$

Comment: @Exodd I have added an attempted solution but I still cannot find its eigenvalues

Comment: Did you try computing $R^2$, and do you know what you can do with the det of a product?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Doesn't that give the usual proof that the determinant of an orthogonal matrix is always either $-1$ or $1$?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I have edited the question, now I understand that the determinant is not necessarily $-1$ but it is something like $(-1)^n$ or $(-1)^d$.

Comment: @Math_Images_Only Do you mind writing it as an answer? I have added some context on how the projection matrix $P$ arises

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I have added some context as to how $\mathrm{P}$ arises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvalues of $P$ are $0$ and $1$, with the multiplicity of $1$ equal to the rank of $P$.  It follows that the eigenvalues of $I - 2 P$ are $1 - 2(0) = 1$ and $1 - 1(1) = -1$, with the multiplicity of $-1$ equal to the rank of $P$.

Because the determinant of a matrix is the product of its eigenvalues, we have
$$
\det(I - 2P) = 1^{n - \operatorname{rank}(P)} (-1)^{\operatorname{rank}(P)} = (-1)^{\operatorname{rank}(P)}.
$$

Comment: Thank you. I am conflicted: I can see numerically and mathematically that your proof is correct. However, I cannot seem to see any problems with the proof given by @ryanon, i.e.
$$
\det(PR) = \det(-P) = (-1)^n \det(P) = \det(P)\det(R) \quad\implies\quad \det(R) = (-1)^n.
$$
This proof uses the fact that $\det(cA) = c^n\det(A)$ and $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$ which seem to be true independently of the rank of $A$ or $B$.

Comment: @Euler_Salter The problem with the proof is that $\det(P) = 0$, so the "$\implies$" is hiding a division by $0$

Comment: Of course! You're right that proof is wrong

Comment: One question: given the eigenvalues of $P$ how do you figure out the eigenvalues of $I - 2P$? I feel like this has to do with the characteristic polynomial

Comment: @Euler_Salter We can make it much simpler than that: if $Pv = \lambda v$, then $(I - 2P)v = v - 2Pv = (1 - 2 \lambda)v$.

Comment: So if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $P$ with geometric multiplicity $k$, then $1 - 2 \lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $I - 2 P$ with geometric multiplicity at least $k$.

Comment: To get the eigenvalues of $P$, note that $P^2 = P$ means that if $P v = \lambda v$ for a non-zero vector $v$, then $P^2 v = Pv \implies \lambda^2 v = \lambda v$. So, all eigenvalues of $P$ must be $0$ or $1$. The fact that the rank of $P$ is equal to the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $1$ is a bit subtler

Comment: To show that, we can use the fact that $P$ is diagonalizable. In particular, we can write every vector $v$ as $v = v_1 + v_2$, where
$$
v_1 = Pv, \quad v_2 = v - Pv.
$$
Notably, $Pv_1 = 1 \cdot v_1$ and $Pv_2 = 0\cdot v_2$. So, every vector can be written as a linear combination of eigenvectors.

Comment: @Euler_Salter To correct my earlier comment, $\det(P)$ is non-zero if and only if $P = I$, in which case the result $\det(I - 2P) = \det(-I) = (-1)^n$ can indeed be correctly deduced.

Answer (score -4):

let $R=I-2P, \;P^2=P$

$det(PR)=det(P(I-2P))\\=det(P-2P^2)=det(P-2P)\\=det(-P)=det(P)det(R)$

now $det(-P)=det(-IP)\\=det(-I)det(P)=-det(P)$

thus:

$det(R)=(-1)^n$.

Comment: $\det(-I)$ is not always -1.

Comment: Isn't $\det(-\mathrm{I}) = (-1)^n$ ? Then it would seem $\det(R) = (-1)^n$ but this is in contrast with the result they found above

Comment: What if $\det P = 0$?

Comment: Right, $det(-I)=(-1)^n$ but i assumed 3 dimensional space

Comment: There is something wrong in this proof because using Python I have checked this for various values of $n$ and various random projection matrices $A$ and the determinant does indeed seem to be $(-1)^{\text{rank}(P)}$

Comment: @ryaron As another commenter noted, this line of reasoning fails because $\det(P)$ is zero (except in the case that $P$ is the identity matrix).